# How do I call a local softphone on freeswitch?

Tags: freeswitch

I've set up a local softphone on freeswitch with the extension 1000. It connects and I can play the tetris theme etc. I would like to call this softphone using a freeswitch command. Can anyone help?

I know it's to do with sofia and originate commands but I can't get them to work

Answer (score 6):

you can use:

```
originate user/1000 &echo()
```

this will connect your phone to the freeswitch to an internal echo function

Answer (score 2):

are you sure your softphone is registered?  This command in CLI should list all registered users:

```
sofia status profile internal reg
```

Comment: Yeah because I can dial 9198 on the softphone and here the tetris theme as stated in the FS manual.

Comment: how about this:  "originate sofia/external/echo@iptel.org 1000"

Answer (score 0):

Originate command connects two endpoints, so you ought to have some other SIP destination or extension to connect with.

Here you can use the music or the echo endpoints, for example: http://www.iptel.org/service

Comment: yes, there are some examples in <a href="http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_commands#originate">Wiki</a>, but as you can see it always specifies two endpoints (one endpoint can be an application execution, such as playback).

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

originate sofia/profile/USER@yourserver.com. But if your developing web-based apps, the enable mod_xml_rpc and use REST to send commands

Answer (score 0):

**while trying to run freeswitch server**

**error : Cannot lock pid file /usr/local/freeswitch/run/freeswitch.pid**

This can be solved in linux(fedora/centos) by following below syntax

1)open terminal

2)press su (to move admin root)

3)enter password

apply the following command

4)**netstat -npl**

then it show all the ports runnning

find port running for freeswitch
ex:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8021          0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      708/freeswitch

5)**fuser -k 708/tcp**
use the number given in response
ex:710

6)kill -9 710

it worked in my system i hope help to run again your freeswitch server thank you